# PayloadValidatingInterceptor not firing for @Endpoint?

Tags: java, validation, spring-ws

I have an application that I would like to automatically validate messages that are received and sent.  I've attached the `PayloadValidatingInterceptor` and set the schema I would like it to use:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        // modifies the wsdl to serve the correct locations
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/*");
    }

    @Bean
    protected PayloadValidatingInterceptor getValidatingInterceptor() {
        PayloadValidatingInterceptor validatingInterceptor = new PayloadValidatingInterceptor();
        validatingInterceptor.setSchema(getResource("classpath:CARetriever.xsd"));
        validatingInterceptor.setValidateRequest(true);
        validatingInterceptor.setValidateResponse(true);
        return validatingInterceptor;
    }

    private Resource getResource(String resource) {
        return ctx.getResource(resource);
    }
}
```

I can see that the interceptor is getting loaded

```
2016-01-21 14:22:08 INFO  org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor,164 - Validating using class path resource [CARetriever.xsd]
```

However, when I throw an invalid SOAP message against it, I get a `NullPointerException` rather than a validation message.  So, either my configuration or expectations are wrong.  Can someone point to which?

Comment: Please, share the StackTrace for that `NPE`. From other side I don't see `addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors)` implementation for adding your `PayloadValidatingInterceptor` to the endpoint mapping...

Comment: I'm not getting a stacktrace - the error is returned in a soap fault response.  As for the `addInterceptors` - when I tried adding it with that method it no longer showed up in the logs.

Comment: That's bad. Any fault is some problem on the server. You should debug your service to figure out who is guilty in that NPE. Re. `addInterceptors()` - I don't know them how it should work... It's your app and we only can recommend and fix some obvious issues. All other your wishes is up to you.

Comment: Well, I assume that it's whatever's unmarshalling the data in the request, since I'm sending it an invalid request.  I could just as easily send it an invalid date and generate a soap fault response with a parse exception message.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error: a SOAPFault with a NPE inside with no stack trace. While debugging I noticed that the validator instance used in PayloadValidatingInterceptor is null, because setSchema does not initialize it. But there is the method setXsdSchema, which *does* initialize it. So, I could fix the NPE using that method instead of setSchema as follows:

```
payloadValidatingInterceptor.setXsdSchema(new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("test.xsd")));
```

For a complete example one may check this example: http://memorynotfound.com/spring-ws-validate-soap-request-response-xsd-schema/

Hope that helps.